# Invalidate java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, kotlin, download, zip, inputstream

i am trying to invalidate a Zip file I am streaming to the browser, to make it impossible for the user to open it.

```
@GetMapping("/downloads/${downloadId}")
fun downloadZip(@PathVariable("downloadId") downloadId: String, response: HttpServletResponse): StreamingResponseBody {
    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachement;filename=\"${download.filename}\"")
    response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
    response.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
    return StreamingResponseBody { out ->
        ZipOutputStream(out).use { zos -> 
            URL(fileUrl).openStream().use { stream ->
                zos.putNextEntry(ZipEntry("target.file")) 
                val bytes: ByteArray
                do {
                    bytes = stream.readNBytes(100000000)
                    val hash = md5(bytes)
                    if (hash != expectedHash) {
                        // What i am looking for
                        zos.invalidate()
                    } 
                    bytes.inputStream().transferTo(zos)
                } while(bytes.size > 0)
                zos.closeEntry()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the server i am checking md5 checksums of chunks and if they are not equal the user shouldn't be able to use the data in the zip.

Do you have a idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Just throw an exception? Or return a 409 Conflict

Comment: I tried this, the zip is still valid and can be opened

Comment: What happens when you just close the `zos`?

Comment: Same, it will still be valid to open. 
One can process the stream twice but this will make the download 2x longer. With files up to 10GB it isn't a good idea :/